# t>=1 or t>=2 => t>=1

Tags: z3

Using Z3, is it possible to somehow merge/simplify

```
t>=2 or t>=1
```

into

```
t>=1
```

where t is an integer?

We wish keep the constraint for t as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z3 can do it by using the tactic `ctx-solver-simplify`.
Note that this tactic may be quite expensive. 
The tactic `ctx-simplify` is cheaper by it only "propagates" equalities.

Here is a link for script using this tactic:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/F7Q

Comment: Thanks! Seems to me (t>=0 and t<=1) or (t>=0 and t<=1) => (t>=0 and t<=1)
But why it return false for the link here： http://rise4fun.com/Z3/aZFY

Comment: Sorry about that. This is bug. We will fix it for the next release.

Comment: Thanks, and also, seems to me (t>=2 and t<=2) => t==2 but link here  http://rise4fun.com/Z3/NHlx doesn't seem to simplify that, is it possible for this simplification?

Comment: The tactic `propagate-ineqs` does the trick. However, this tactic only consider inequalities and equalities that are not nested inside the formula. So, it will not work for `(p or (t>=2 and t<=2))`

Comment: The link is broken (and web.archive doesn't record it). Could you paste this code snippet again? Very thanks!