# how to use z3 to get valid range of a variable

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to find the range of valid values that a variable can have, given some constraints. Eg,

```
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x >= 1)
s.add(x < 5+2)
```

Is there some way that I can get z3 to print  1..6 for this variable?

I tried using the following, but range() applies only to declarations.

```
print("x.range():", x.range()) # this does not work
```

**Note:** 1. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507360) seems to ask the same, but I did not understand its answers, and I am looking for python answer.

2. in reply to @Malte: I am not looking for all the answers, I just want to simplify multiple constraints in to a valid range. If constraints on both sides of the variable cannot be merged, then at least only on one side as is mentioned in above mentioned question.

Comment: I don't see how getting Z3 to print the range `[1,6]` of potential values for `x` is different from getting Z3 to print all valid models. Please clarify. Note that the question you linked to appears to differ from yours in that you'd like to find a simple representation for all models, whereas in the linked question, a simplified representation of an initial set of constraints is wanted.

Comment: It matters if the range is high. Eg, if the range happens to be [1,10000], I dont want to enumerate all 10k answers to determine its range.

Comment: In the linked answer, it is simplifying all constraints on one side, ie on >= side. But I was asking for range, which is equivalent to simplifying constraints on both sides.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, Z3 does not directly support what you're asking for. Enumerating of all possible answers is the only option you have. Together with filing a feature request (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues), of course :-)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. BTW, the mentioned question has a non-python answer, is there a python equivalent for it?

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up occasionally, and the answer isn't very trivial, unfortunately. It really depends on what your constraints are and exactly what you are trying to do. See:

[Is it possible to get a legit range info when using a SMT constraint with Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676016/is-it-possible-to-get-a-legit-range-info-when-using-a-smt-constraint-with-z3)

And

[(Sub)optimal way to get a legit range info when using a SMT constraint with Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733658/suboptimal-way-to-get-a-legit-range-info-when-using-a-smt-constraint-with-z3)

Essentially, the problem is too difficult (and I'd say not even well defined) if you have multiple variables. If you have exactly one variable, you can use the optimizer to some extent, assuming the variable is indeed bounded. In case you have multiple variables, one idea might be to fix all but one to satisfying constants, and compute the range of that last variable based on the constant assignment to the others. But again, it depends on what you're really trying to achieve.

Please take a look at the above two answers and see if it helps you. If not, please show us what you tried: Stack-overflow works the best when you post some code and see how it can be improved/fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As a SAT/SMT solver, Z3 "only" needs to find a single model (satisfying assignment) to show that a formula is satisfiable. Finding all models is therefore not directly supported.

The question comes up regularly, though, and the solution is to repeatedly find and then block (assume in negated form) models until no further model can be found. For example, for your snippet of code:

```py
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x >= 1)
s.add(x < 5+2)

result = s.check()

while result == sat:
  m = s.model()
  print("Model: ", m)
  
  v_x = m.eval(x, model_completion=True)

  s.add(x != v_x)
  result = s.check()

print(result, "--> no further models")
```

Executing the script yields the solution you asked for, albeit in a less concise form:

```
Model:  [x = 1]
Model:  [x = 2]
Model:  [x = 3]
Model:  [x = 4]
Model:  [x = 5]
Model:  [x = 6]
unsat --> no further models
```

In general,

- you would have iterate over all variables (here: just `x`)
- model completion is necessary for variables whose value doesn't affect satisfiability; since any value will do, they won't be explicit in the model

Related questions whose answers provide additional details:

- [(Z3Py) checking all solutions for equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611)
- [Why Z3Py does not provide all possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162290)
- [Getting all solutions of a boolean expression in Z3Py never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866787)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added some more details in the question.