I want to build a z3 solver that prints the range instead of printing all possible values
Suppose I have an expression x as an integer. So minimum and maximum value of that integer would be INT_MIN and INT_MAX if I don't apply any constraint. But suppose I apply a constraint a such that a implies !(m>=0 && m<=10) so my model would generate answers like INT_MIN to 99 and 501 to INT_MAX. It would give all possible values of it. But instead of printing all possible values can it print valid range and can it work for multiple constraints.
Consider the code.
#include <iostream>
#include <z3++.h>

using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    context c;
    solver s(c);

    expr x = c.int_const("x");
    expr a = c.bool_const("a");

    expr range_constraint = (x >= -100 && x <= 100);


    expr constraint = implies(a, (x >= 0 && x <= 10));

    s.add(range_constraint);
    s.add(!constraint);

    while (s.check() == sat) {
       
        model m = s.get_model();

    
        cout << m.eval(x) << endl;

   
        expr current_solution = (x == m.eval(x));

        
        s.add(!current_solution);
    }

    return 0;
}

I want the output as [-100,-1][11,100]

But instead of printing all possible values can it print valid range and can it work for multiple constraints. - is this your question?

Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63380049/936310
Long story short, no you cannot do this in general. An SMT solver finds a particular satisfying solution (or many solutions if you program it to do so), but it does not give you a symbolic "range" of where the solution might lie. In general, doing so is well beyond the capabilities of what SMT solvers can do. (That is, it's a much much harder problem.)
I should also add that an int value in SMT is unbounded. It's not a machine-integer: It's a mathematical integer. If you want machine-integers, you should instead use bit-vectors.
Having said that, you can get ranges if you have a-priori knowledge on what those ranges are. For instance, if you somehow know that x <= c0 and x >= c1 for some constants c0 and c1, then you can ask the SMT solver to find you those by using quantifiers. (Whether this will be performant is entirely problem specific: Adding quantifiers make the logic semi-decidable; so z3 may respond unknown or fail to terminate.) But the important point is that this has to be a-priori: i.e., you have to have additional information about the problem outside of the solver yourself (perhaps via some other mathematical/symbolic analysis), and you should have a skeleton of what the range looks like. You can then ask the SMT solver to find the relevant constants.
But the way you're describing the problem, sounds like you want z3 to "automagically" give you these ranges; and that's not something it'll do for you. There's no automatic way of determining such ranges. But see the answer I linked above for some ideas and why the problem is really difficult in general, especially if you have multiple variables.

Is it possible that can I print the ranges explicitly, by building some logic. If yes can you please give me some rough idea how I can do it.

I’m not sure what you mean. Did you read the linked answer and the discussion there?

Yes. I read it. Actually I am new to z3 and i want to work on it. So basically my task is to print range of an int variable after applying multiple constraints on it. But theres no any inbuilt function to do it. So i was asking can it be done by writing some piece of code?

As explained there, no there isn’t. Unless you already know the exact shape of these intervals.

One can use boxed-optimization to get min/max values for N optimization variables. That does not exactly do what the OP asks, since it would return a single range per variable and it would be over-approximated (see: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~aws/papers/popl14.pdf).
I think it should be possible to modify z3 to do what you want though. Computing the min/max for every satisfiable assignment is what we do for optimization. You'd have to keep track of the ranges instead of discarding it as we commonly do in the boxed optimization. Same caveats for boxed optimization would apply wrt. ranges.

Patrick: That's a great idea; but in practice I think you still need to have some "assumptions." Imagine two Int variables, with the only constraint a != b. What are the ranges for a and b? Clearly each choice of a (or b) leads to a different range for the other. I think the problem is not well defined as stated. But if there are restrictions put on the exact shape of the problem and if there's some a-priori knowledge about what these intervals look like, perhaps one can concoct something that works well enough for practical purposes.

The above suggestion ties into the same caveats for boxed optimization, which would treat value assignments as independent. It would thus yield [-oo, oo] for both variables, since it can find some assignment for each variable in which it has a value over the entire range. i.e. it finds value assignments that are globally infeasible, as opposed to value assignments that are globally feasible (represented in a dual way). I do agree with you the problem is not well defined as stated.
